# Cannot open include file config.h

Tags: visual-c++, include, compiler-errors, file-not-found

One of the header files uses

```
#include <config.h>
```

but I keep getting the error

> Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config.h': No such file or directory

and I don't know why. config.h is in the headers folder in the project and when I right-click on it, I can actually open the file too, but I still get this error when building the project.

Comment: I mean in the code, I can actually click on the #include <config.h> line and open the file from there. So visual studios clearly knows what file it's supposed to be referencing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That must mean the directory is not added to the extra include directories tab in the project properties. If the header is not in the same location as the source file, it doesn't matter if it's added to the project or not.

Go to **Project properties** (right click on project) -> **Configuration Properties** -> **C/C++** -> **General** -> **Additional include directories** and add the directory where the header resides (probably something like "./headers").

Comment: @SSEMember that's can't be. You probably made a typo somewhere.

Comment: I think that worked. I included the directory that all the files were in and got a different set of errors that I know are unrelated. Thanks. Although I'm still unclear as to why the project couldn't find the .h files, even though there were in the same directory as the .c files.

Comment: Alright, I'm pretty sure I know where it's trying to compile them vs where they are. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There must be another possibility. I'm having the same problem, and I've moved my header file to a variety of different _include directories_ and it still produces the same error.

Comment: Never mind. The file was in the right directory within the project, but VS's project structure doesn't propagate back out to the disc. You might want to specify in your answer that you're referring to disc directories and not project directories as that is an irritating distinction. >:(